# Create a User Control which uses another User Control

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, user-controls

I have a User Control which acts as a TrackBar with a `SelectedMin`, `Value`, and `SelectedMax` within the bounds of a `Min` and `Max`.

I now want to create another User Control as a kind of shell to the above User Control so as to include hovering labels to display the current value of each of the selected values.

I want to do this in a separate User Control because it seems like a pain to shift everything down to make room for the value labels within the TrackBar User Control.

Here's my current `CustomTrackBar.cs` User Control. Sorry, it's messy:

```
public partial class CustomTrackBar : UserControl
{

    #region variables
    private int min = 0;
    private int max = 1000;
    private int selectedMin = 0;
    private int selectedMax;
    private int value;

    private int sliderWidth = 2;
    #endregion

    #region accessors

    public int Min
    {
        get { return min; }
        set { min = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    public int Max
    {
        get { return max; }
        set { max = value; Invalidate(); }
    }

    public int SelectedMin
    {
        get { return selectedMin; }
        set
        {
            selectedMin = value;
            if (AnythingChanged != null)
            {
                //SelectionChanged(this, null);
                AnythingChanged(this, null);
            }
            MinChanged = true;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int SelectedMax
    {
        get { return selectedMax; }
        set
        {
            selectedMax = value;
            if (AnythingChanged != null)
            {
                //SelectionChanged(this, null);
                AnythingChanged(this, null);
            }
            MaxChanged = true;
            Invalidate();
            MaxChanged = false;
        }
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            if (AnythingChanged != null)
            {
                //ValueChanged(this, null);
                AnythingChanged(this, null);
            }
            ValueChanged = true;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int SliderWidth
    {
        get { return sliderWidth; }
        set
        {
            this.sliderWidth = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public Boolean MinChanged
    {
        get; private set;
    }
    public Boolean ValueChanged
    {
        get; private set;
    }
    public Boolean MaxChanged
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    #endregion

    //Fired when SelectedMin or SelectedMax changes.
    //public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;

    //Fired when Value changes.
    //public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    //Fired if anything changes
    public event EventHandler AnythingChanged;


    public CustomTrackBar()
    {
        //Set default values
        Value = (Max - Min) / 2;
        SelectedMax = Max;

        SliderWidth = SliderWidth / (Max - Min); //this line is horrible

        InitializeComponent();



        //Avoid flickering
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

        //Events
        Paint += new PaintEventHandler(CustomTrackBar_Paint);
        MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(CustomTrackBar_MouseDown);
        MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(CustomTrackBar_MouseMove);
    }

    //Create a rectangle
    void CustomTrackBar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //paint background in white
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, ClientRectangle);

        //Create a rectangle object
        Rectangle selectionRect = new Rectangle(
            0,
            0,
            Width,
            Height);

        /*
        Rectangle selectionRect = new Rectangle(
        (SelectedMin - Min) * Width / (Max - Min),
        15,
        (SelectedMax - selectedMin) * Width / (Max - Min),
        Height - 30);
        */

        //paint the rectangle object
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.GreenYellow, selectionRect);

        //Again how does this work?
        Rectangle firstFrameRect = new Rectangle(
            (SelectedMin - SliderWidth/2) * Width / (Max - Min),
            0,
            SliderWidth * Width / (Max - Min),
            Height
            );
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkBlue, firstFrameRect);


        Rectangle lastFrameRect = new Rectangle(
            (SelectedMax - SliderWidth/2) * Width / (Max - Min),
            0,
            SliderWidth * Width / (Max - Min),
            Height
            );

         /*
            Rectangle lastFrameRect = new Rectangle(
            SelectedMax * Width / (Max - Min),
            0,
            5 * Width / (Max - Min),
            Height
            );
         */

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.OrangeRed, lastFrameRect);


        //draw a black frame around our control
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);

        //draw a simple vertical line at the Value position
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black,
            (Value - Min) * Width / (Max - Min) - 5,
            0,
            (Value - Min) * Width / (Max - Min) - 5,
            Height);
    }

    void CustomTrackBar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //check where the user clicked so we can decide which thumb to move
        int pointedValue = Min + e.X * (Max - Min) / Width;
        int distValue = Math.Abs(pointedValue - Value);
        int distMin = Math.Abs(pointedValue - SelectedMin);
        int distMax = Math.Abs(pointedValue - SelectedMax);
        int minDist = Math.Min(distValue, Math.Min(distMin, distMax));
        if (minDist == distValue)
            movingMode = MovingMode.MovingValue; //this should only move when video plays
        else if (minDist == distMin)
            movingMode = MovingMode.MovingMin;
        else
            movingMode = MovingMode.MovingMax;
        //call this to refreh the position of the selected thumb
        CustomTrackBar_MouseMove(sender, e);
    }

    void CustomTrackBar_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //if the left button is pushed, move the selected thumb
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
            return;
        int pointedValue = Min + e.X * (Max - Min) / Width;
        if (movingMode == MovingMode.MovingValue)
        {
            if (pointedValue <= Max && pointedValue >= Min)
                Value = pointedValue;
        }
        else if (movingMode == MovingMode.MovingMin)
        {
            if (pointedValue < SelectedMax && pointedValue >= Min)
                SelectedMin = pointedValue;
        }
        else if (movingMode == MovingMode.MovingMax)
        {
            if (pointedValue > SelectedMin && pointedValue <= Max)
                SelectedMax = pointedValue;
        }
    }


    //To know which thumb is moving
    enum MovingMode { MovingValue, MovingMin, MovingMax }
    MovingMode movingMode;

    public String AllValues()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", SelectedMin, Value, SelectedMax);
    }

}
```

Here's what the CustomTrackBar looks like right now. The vertical Blue, Black, and Red lines are able to be clicked and dragged:

[image]

Here's a sketch of what I intend to have it look like:

[image]

I don't really know how to start new User Control. I tried to make a CustomTrackBar object in the new User Control, but that doesn't seem to draw anything.

Also, is it "correct" to create another User Control to add pieces to the TrackBar? Should I just tough it out and do everything inside the first User Control?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should do when a new control you built isn't drawing is verify that it has the correct non-zero dimensions and you didn't override the drawing code(which you did in `CustomTrackBar_Paint`). You should prefer composition to custom drawing unless you have a strong grasp on the coordinate space and what your drawing code is actually doing.

What I mean by composition is splitting the control into a container with multiple inner controls, all of which already exist in the framework. You could for example make your `UserControl`, backdrop, and bars [Panels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=vs.110).aspx), and the numbers [Labels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx). Position and size them correctly, updating when the slider value/min/max/etc changes. If you do this, you simplify your code and don't have to touch the drawing code.

Something like this:

```
public partial class CustomTrackBar : Panel
{
    private Panel backdrop;
    private Panel minBar;
    private Panel maxBar;
    private Panel currentBar;
    private Label minDisplay;
    private Label maxDisplay;
    private Label currentDisplay;

    public CustomTrackBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // This should almost always be first.
        backdrop = new Panel() {
            BackColor = Color.LightGreen,
            // set position, size, etc.
        };
        // add event handlers to backdrop...
        Controls.Add(backdrop);
        // repeat for minBar, maxBar, etc.

        SizeChanged += (sender, args) => {
            Update();
        };

        // ... remaining initialization logic.
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // adjust the position and size of each inner control...
    }
}
```

Only once you've done that, and measured a performance impact, should you move to custom drawing. This will allow you to make incremental changes with working code rather than taking a stab at it in the dark.

Comment: This is definitely a better way to go about creating a custom trackbar. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I'm having difficulty placing panels within other panels and making sure they're all visible. I've placed a `backdropPanel` on a new user control and place 3 additional `panels` within that `backdropPanel` and they appear to be underneath and not visible. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: I forgot to mention: Unlike many other frameworks, WinForms doesn't use a z-index, but rather the order of the children. This means the order of the children determines the layering. <code>backdropPanel</code> appears on top because it's the first control added, and has the 0th place. Earlier controls appear before later controls. See the next comment for a solution.

Comment: There are several ways of changing the order. One way is adding them in a manner that achieves the order you want. Other more direct ways include [BringToFront](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(v=vs.110).aspx), [SendToBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback(v=vs.110).aspx), and [SetChildIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx)

Comment: A lack of x-index in Forms really seems inconvenient. So if I'm trying to make an outline for each of my Panels, do I need to use a black background Panel just a little bigger than the main panel since the rectangle won't necessarily be in the foreground?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153310/discussion-between-koby-duck-and-tawm).